# Are there examples for ODEs with complex coefficients with applications in physics?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

I have stumbled upon this paper
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089396591630324X

It made me wonder:

Are there examples for ordinary differential equations with complex coefficients that have applications in physics ? A reference or link would be very helpful.

Comment: What would be the motivation for a coefficients to be imaginary? Perhaps very advanced physics will have an equation like this, but I can't see what it would be for most applications. Most terms in ODEs have a clear physical interpretation, for example $mx'' + b x' + k x = 0$ (a mass $m$ attached to spring with constant $k$ and damping $b$).

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but two things spring to mind. Schrodinger's equation (which is a PDE not ODE) and the harmonic oscillator $\ddot x=-\omega^2 x$ which you could rejiggle into $\dot x=i\omega x$.

Comment: I can't think of one at the top of my head, but complex numbers are popular in the field of electrical engineering.  (It simplifies analysis of inductor/capacitor circuits if you treat them as resistors with non-real resistance.  Also, Fourier transforms for signal processing.)  So you might want to start your search there.